# XPATH return contents of an html element based on the name within the element above

Tags: html, xpath

```
<div class="vdatatable">
  <div class="rowh">Emissions
  </div>
  <a name="anc0"></a>
  <div class="optexrow oid0 row " data-oid="0">
    <div class="key">CO2 Emissions
    </div>
    <div class="value">117 g/km 
    </div>
    <div class="cf">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a name="anc0"></a>
  <div class="optexrow oid0 row1 " data-oid="0">
    <div class="key">Standard Euro Emissions
    </div>
    <div class="value">EURO6 
    </div>
    <div class="cf">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rowh">Engine and Drive Train
  </div>
  <a name="anc0"></a>
  <div class="optexrow oid0 row " data-oid="0">
    <div class="key">Engine Size
    </div>
    <div class="value">998 cc 
    </div>
    <div class="cf">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a name="anc0"></a>
  <div class="optexrow oid0 row1 " data-oid="0">
    <div class="key">Gears
    </div>
    <div class="value">5 
    </div>
    <div class="cf">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a name="anc0"></a>
  <div class="optexrow oid0 row " data-oid="0">
    <div class="key">Number of Valves
    </div>
    <div class="value">12 
    </div>
    <div class="cf">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a name="anc0"></a>
  <div class="optexrow oid0 row1 " data-oid="0">
    <div class="key">Transmission
    </div>
    <div class="value">Manual 
    </div>
    <div class="cf">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rowh">Fuel Consumption
  </div>
  <a name="anc0"></a>
  <div class="optexrow oid0 row " data-oid="0">
    <div class="key">EC Combined 
    </div>
    <div class="value">50.4 mpg 
    </div>
    <div class="cf">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to return the data within the div class "rowh". But based on the name "Emissions". I only want that data, not the data from the next div down which has the exact same class but has the name "Engine and Drive Train". I have tried many variations:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'optexrow')]/div[@class='key']/ancestor::div[starts-with(., 'Emissions')]

//div[contains(@class, 'rowh') and contains(., 'Emissions')]/div[@class=key]

//div[preceding-sibling::div[starts-with(., 'Emissions')] and following-sibling::div[@class = 'rowh']]
```

But cannot isolate the div I want. Keeps picking up ALL divs on the page. Expected result should be:

```
CO2 Emissions
117 g/km
Standard Euro Emissions
EURO6
```

Comment: As HTML does not have an XPath function can you clarify the language you are hoping to use for this? PHP, Javascript - other...?

Comment: Hi, I use Google Chrome plugin and also a custom build tool. I would have to assume the tool is php. I use xpath with html pages all the time, using queries like I mention above. I just cannot get the correct one!

Answer (score 0):

You can use following expression:
//div[@class="rowh" and contains(text(), "Emissions")]
@class to filter class type "rowh" and Contains method to filter text with "Emissions".

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. What is the query I need to use?

Answer (score 0):

//self::div[contains(@data-oid, '0') and contains(., 'Emissions')or contains(., 'Fuel Consumption')]

is this what you are looking for?

Comment: No, because it won't pick up this one: /"/self::div[contains(@data-oid, '0') and contains(., 'Fuel Consumption')]"

Comment: //self::div[contains(@data-oid, '0') and contains(., 'Emissions')or contains(., 'Fuel Consumption')]

Comment: I want to use one query for each separate piece of data. Not combined. In your example, when I change "Emissions" to "Fuel Consumption" for my next query, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried many variations:
>   `//div[contains(@class, 'optexrow')]/div[@class='key']/ancestor::div[starts-with(., 'Emissions')]`

`<div class="rowh">Emissions</div>` is a sibling to `<div class="optexrow oid0 row " data-oid="0">`, not an ancestor.

> `//div[contains(@class, 'rowh') and contains(., 'Emissions')]/div[@class=key]`

`<div class="rowh">Emissions</div>` doesn't have any child-nodes. `<div class="key">CO2 Emissions</div>` is a child-node of a sibling.

I can think of the following queries that produce what you want:

```
//div[starts-with(text(),'Emissions')]//following-sibling::div[position()<3]/div[@class=('key','value')]/normalize-space(text())
```

- Select the 2 `div`s you're after by using hard positions.
- Select the child `div`s with an attribute which has a value `key` and `value` and return the normalized text-node.
- (The other way around; `div[@class!='cf']` would also work.)

```
//div[starts-with(@class,'optexrow') and following-sibling::div[starts-with(text(),'Engine')]]/div[@class=('key','value')]/normalize-space(text())
```

- Select all `<div class="optexrow[...]">` *"until"* `<div class="rowh">Engine[...]</div>`
- (`. << ../div[...]` instead of `following-sibling::div[...]` would also work.)

Both queries would return:

```
CO2 Emissions
117 g/km
Standard Euro Emissions
EURO6
```

Answer (score 0):

This XPath expression:

```
//div[contains(concat(' ',normalize-space(@class),' '),' rowh ')][contains(.,'Emissions')]
     /following-sibling::div[1]
```

Selects:

```
<div class="optexrow oid0 row " data-oid="0"> 
  <div class="key">CO2 Emissions</div>  
  <div class="value">117 g/km</div>  
  <div class="cf"/> 
</div>
```

Test in [here](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/143d17b4ea2bac8b1e39467391e51714)

**Do note:** correct class idiom, use of following-sibling axis with positional predicate.